# Правильное написание словосочетания "образцах сока"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно писать:
В образцах сока
или
В образцах соков

Comment: Образцах сока. Сок слишком общее понятие, не как вино - в образцах вин. Но, если будет в образцах соков - то это не ошибка. Соки-воды раньше отдел назывался, образец вод тоже говорят.

Answer (score 2):

По всей видимости, вы больше погружены в контекст (или общую ситуацию, в которой вы пишете текст) - значит, вам и выбирать правильное решение. Если вы пишете об одном и том же соке от разных производителей, то пишите об "образцах (такого-то) сока" (есть смысл позаботиться о том, чтобы в каждом конкретном упоминании ваш читатель чётко понимал, о соке какого производителя идёт сейчас речь). Если же вы пишете о разных соках от разных производителей, то пишите об "образцах соков" (опять-таки, поставьте себя на место вашего читателя и позаботьтесь о его интересах - избегайте путаницы).